Bed seems to move down too fast
When I'm printing, at the start, the bed is at the right level, but as I print, the bed goes down slightly too fast, resulting in the ~5th layer no longer sticking, and all layers afterwards, how would I go about fixing this
My printer is the CreateBot-DE02 old model(No touchscreen).
